# how to make query selections before ->get() use query builder in laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i would like to do some query like this

```
$query = User::where($a,$b);
if($options){
    $query = $query->where($c,$d)->get();
}
else{
    $query->get();
}
```

but there is something wrong with `$query`,so how to achieve the selection during query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
$query = User::where($a, $b);

if ($options) {
    $query->where($c, $d);
}

if ($c) {
    $query->orderBy('id', DESC);
}

// You can add other options to your query before calling the get() function

$query = $query->get();
```

If $options is true, then it will run this SQL:

`select * from users where $a = $b and $c = $d`

If $options is false:

`select * from users where $a = $b`

Comment: not only this,i'm looking for wherever to stop and make some selections happen during query,could it achieve?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add additional options without getting?

Comment: yes,means save the query temporarily like what codeigniter could do

Comment: Did you try the above code? Until you call the get() method, you can append additional options to your query using the method above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
$users = User::query();

if($options) {
    $users->where(a$, $b);
} else {
    $users->where($c, $d);
}

$users->get();
```